# Passing an array of images through input field to server

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How can I pass an array variable containing my images in the form of DataURL to my server?

```
Example of array
["aug.jpg,data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAAAADTLQAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAlkZXNjAAAA8AAAAHRyWFlaAAABZAAAABRnWFlaAAABeAAAABRiWFlaAAABjAAAABRyVFJDA......]
```

I have tried to **JSON.stringify** the value of the array on the front end and attempt to **json_decode** on the backend but it results in an error :

> "error_log() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

I have also tried creating a hidden input field for each array of images(dataURL) that I have and serializing the value but when receiving the value of the input on the server, i am unable to convert it back to an array.

```
for (let k = 0; k < Object.keys(savedImageFilesArray_complex_form).length; k++) {
    console.log("Appending image");
    var img_item = (savedImageFilesArray_complex_form[k]);
    //img_item=JSON.stringify(['testing','testing123']);

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "finalImageFilesComplexForm"+k+"[]";
    input.class = 'serializeImages' +k;
    input.value = img_item
    appendArea.appendChild(input);

    $('.serializeImages'+k).serialize();
}
```

(Edited with server code)

Appended below is the value that i am receiving on the $request on the server end.
[image]

When trying to json_decode the value, it results in the error as mentioned earlier with the parameter 1 being a string rather than an array

```
  error_log(json_decode($request['finalImageFilesComplexForm0'][0]));
```

Comment: The error message sounds like it's not directly related to your json_decode function. It sounds like you've tried to log an error but haven't used the error_log function correctly. Please check the documentation page and then adjust  your code accordingly: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php . As the error message and the documentation makes clear, the first parameter you pass into the error_log() function must be a string - but presumably you're trying to send it an array. If you need any help with fixing that, please update your question with the relevant bits of PHP code.

Comment: BTW your client-side code looks a little odd...surely it would be simpler to use a FormData object rather than creating hidden fields on the fly. Or just serialize the data to JSON as you mentioned - but if you do that make sure you set the content-type of your request to "application/json" to match that (I assume it's an AJAX request?).

Comment: @ADyson i have added in some of the relevant backend code. Kindly do help me identify where i have gone wrong

Comment: Well (it should hopefully be obvious that) `json_decode` will return a PHP array, if you pass a JSON array into it. And as the error message says, you can't pass an array into error_log(). If you're wanting to log the JSON which was sent from the client-side, then that's going to be logged as text (because a log file is a text file). JSON is text already. A string is also text. If you decode the JSON, it stops being text and starts being a PHP array (or object). Therefore, you should just log the raw JSON directly without decoding it.

Comment: @ADyson how am i suppose to iterate through $request['finalImageFilesComplexForm0'] in a for each loop?

i have tried         foreach($request['finalImageFilesComplexForm0'] as $test){
            error_log($test);
            error_log(gettype($test));
        } to no avail

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just `error_log($request['finalImageFilesComplexForm0'][0]);` should do the trick - that will log the raw JSON string. That's what I meant.